# Android Theme.Holo.Light on Galaxy Nexus has grey background when emulator does not

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

When I use the theme Theme.Holo.Light, my window background appears white on the emulator (same as using Theme.Light from earlier Android versions).  However on the Galaxy Nexus it appears as a light grey.  I've taken a screenshot and found it is actually a very slight gradient.

Here is a brand new project created with ADT16.  All I have done is set the theme in the manifest:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
```

and for contrast put this in the activity:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="This text background is white"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:background="#fff" />
```

[Here's the screenshot from the emulator running API 15 (and is identical on API 14)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1v2w.png).

[Here it is on a real Galaxy Nexus.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAX2q.png)

Why the difference? I know not to trust manufacturers not to mess with the AOSP themes on older Android versions, but (i) this is a Nexus device and (ii) Holo is supposed to be mandatory and unmodified on all devices with Market (http://android-developers.blogspot.co.nz/2012/01/holo-everywhere.html).

(Perhaps someone with an ICS device other than Galaxy Nexus can tell me what they get for Holo.Light - maybe it is an emulator bug.)

Comment: I've seen the same gradient in screenshots of certain apps but not others. That gradient is visible in screenshots from both a Galaxy Nexus and a Nexus S running the official 4.0.4 firmware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theme.Holo.Light does have a grey background.

The screenshot from your Nexus shows the right behaviour.

Best wishes,
Tim

Comment: Thanks. That doesn't answer my why question though. I've had to add a windowBackground of #fff3f3f3 to my theme so I can test it properly in the emulator.  This seems like an obvious bug, but I can't find it in the AOSP bug tracker.

Answer (score 0):

use this in your theme

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/your_color</item>
```